# How to convert anchor tag into button in magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, css

I want to convert this "Notify me when this product is in stock" anchor tag into button and it should be open in new tab on click.

Steps to reproduce issue:

Step 1: Enable To Display Out of Stock Products In Frontend

- In admin panel, go to Stores → Configuration → Catalog → Inventory.
- Go to the Stock Options → Display Out of Stock Products → “Yes”
- Click on “Save Config” button

Step 2: Enable “Notify me when this product is in stock” When Product is Back in Stock

- Go to the Stores → Configuration → Catalog → Product Alerts.
- Product alerts → Allow Alert When Product Comes Back in Stock → “Yes”.
- Click on “Save Config” button

  [image]

Now I want to change "Notify me when this product is in stock" anchor tag into button and it should be open in new tab on click.

I found below code into "vendor/magento/module-product-alert/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml" But, I am not getting how to do it. Kindly assist me to do it, Thanks in advance

```
<block class="Magento\ProductAlert\Block\Product\View\Stock" name="productalert.stock" as="productalert_stock" template="Magento_ProductAlert::product/view.phtml">
            <action method="setHtmlClass">
                <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">stock</argument>
            </action>
            <action method="setSignupLabel">
                <argument translate="true" name="value" xsi:type="string">Notify me when this product is in stock</argument>
            </action>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you will have to override the following template in your theme and change the anchor tag to a button tag via HTML

- `vendor/magento/module-product-alert/view/frontend/templates/product/view.phtml`

Some info on overriding templates in themes:

- https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/templates/override/#template-overrides
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VF3I7RiBVEM

Comment: yes, I done with same. Thank you